# Google Cloud Shell scripting Issue

Tags: python-3.x, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running my code from the shell(SSH) in google cloud as

> python3 mycode.py

If I close the shell, the computation stops. How can I start a computation and then close the shell(Computation takes a long Time:)).....come back later and see how it is doing.

My code keeps printing results after a certain number of iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in general what you can do is run the code in a way where you can detach from the interactive environment. Using a tool such as `screen` or `tmux`. However, Google Cloud Shell is not made for running background tasks, and if i recall correctly, it will terminate after an hour.

You might need to provision a virtual machine to run it on instead. I can recommend using tmux. With tmux, it will be as simple as running `tmux` and then in the new shell running your script `python3 mycode.py`. You can then detach using `ctrl+b d` or simply disconnect. When you reconnect you run `tmux attach -d`to get back to your script.

Comment: Thank You. It worked. Can I create multiple VM instances from my shell?

Comment: You should be able to create VM instances from the google cloud control panel, I am not sure you can do it directly from the shell.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance  For example `gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME]
    --image-family [IMAGE_FAMILY]
    --image-project [IMAGE_PROJECT]` but there are many flags and options depending on which kind of machine you want to create

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you as well the following possibility:

A [Bash Builtin command](https://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/disown/) that you could also use is `disown`. First, run your process/script in the background (using `&`, or stopping it with `^Z` and then restarting with `bg`):

```
$ long_operation_command &
[1] 1156
```

> Note that at this point the process is still linked to the session and in case it is closed it will be killed.
>   You can the process attached to the session check running `jobs` in the background:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running  long_operation_command
```

Therefore you can run disown in order to detach the processes from the session:

```
$ disown
```

You can confirm this checking the result of your script or command logging in again or checking with  `top` the process still running.

Check also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and?newreg=cb61c5c7450d45cebf32582e6ac5fd3e) because it could be interesting, i.e. the difference between `nohup foo`, `foo &` and `$ foo & disown`